# Убрать форму после успешной регистрации

Tags: php, pdo

Есть код страницы регистрации:

```
<div class="wrap">
<form class="registration"  method="post">
<?php 
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['usrname'])) ){
        if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $passwd = $_POST['password'];
            $secpasswd = $_POST['secondpassword'];
            $email = $_POST['email']; 

            if(empty($name) || empty($passwd) || empty($secpasswd) || empty($email)){
                echo "<p style= color:red;>Заполните все поля!!!<p>";
            }
            if($passwd != $secpasswd){
                echo "<p style= color:red;>Пароли не совпадают!!!<p>";
            }
            if(strlen($name) < 5 || strlen($passwd) < 5){
                echo "<p style= color:red;>Логин и пароль должны быть не короче 5 символов!!!<p>";
            }else{  
                $_POST['scs'] = 1;
                $db = Db::getConnection();
                $check  = $db->query
                ("SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` 
                WHERE `user_name` ='".$name."';");


                if($check->fetch() != false){
                    echo "<p style= color:red;>Такой логин уже занят!!!<p>";
                }else{

                $insert = $db->query(
                "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`, `admin`)
                 VALUES (NULL,'".$name."' , '".$passwd."','".$email."', 'NULL');");


                $LogList=array();
                $result = $db->query
                ("SELECT*FROM `users` 
                WHERE `user_name`='".$name."' 
                AND `user_password`='".$passwd."' ");
                $row = $result->fetch();
                $LogList['id'] = $row['id'];
                $LogList['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
                $LogList['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                $LogList['admin'] = $row['admin'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $LogList['id'];
                $_SESSION['usrname'] = $LogList['user_name'];
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $LogList['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $LogList['admin'];
                echo "<p style=color:red;>Вы успешно зарегестрированы!!<p>";
                }
            }
    }?>

    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
<p>Логин:</p> <input class="reg-in" type="text" name="name">
    <p>e-mail:</p> <input class="reg-in" type="email" name="email">
    <p>Пароль: </p><input class="reg-in" type="password" name="password">
    <p>Повторите пароль :</p> <input class="reg-in" type="password" name="secondpassword">
    <p><input type="submit" class="reg-but" value="Зарегестрироваться" name="reg"></p>
</form> <?php
 }else{
    echo "<p style=color:red>Вы уже зарегистрированы!!!</p>";
 } ?>
```

Проблема: После успешной регистрации форма остается, и убирается только после обновления страницы.Сессии как видите не помогают, т.к почему то заносятся в массив после повторного обновления страницы.
Как я могу сделать так, чтобы именно после успешной регистрации форма убралась, и вывело сообщение????

Comment: Используйе `ajax`, если не хотите перезагружать страницу.. Там и форму удалите и текст вывидете..

Comment: @Cactus А без аякса никак нелзья????Просто я думал сдесь аякс не к месту юзать и можно сделать по другому

Comment: Навряд что-то можно придумать..

Comment: @Cactus Забавно, я 7 часов потратил, чтобы попытаться найти ответ, который мне советовали с самого начала

Comment: Ну все-таки без перезагрузки никак без аякса, это надо учесть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать простое решение, после того как пользователь прошёл регистрацию, вы записали данные в базу и создали `SESSION`, можете просто
обновить страницу (или сделать редирект на главную) и уже при показе формы регистрации проверяете есть ли `$_SESSION['id']`, если есть `ID` то пользователь зарегистрирован (или залогинился), если нет `ID` значит можете показывать форму регистрации (или форму для входа)

```
if(empty($_SESSION['id']){

/*Форма регистрации */
}
```

> Обновленно

Сессии сразу записываются, однако они могут показать данные только после перезагрузки, поэтой причине я указал что надо сделать редирект и после проверять

Comment: @Cactus я ответил на данный вопрос в ответе(обновил)

Comment: Я пытался сделать редирект с помощью header, но он выдает ошибку, и пытался обновить страницу с помощью  JS функции location.reload(), он не работал по какой то причине, можно ли сделать редирект каким либо еще способом?()

Comment: @Arsen, да, хорошо:)

Comment: @NONAME какую ошибку выдаёт при редиректе header ? как вы вствляете редирект ?

Comment: @Arsen Если я вставляю header в конце то он выдает ошибку согласно manual: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ,т.к header нельзя ставить после загрузки страницы, а если вначале пытаюсь дать редирект на ту же страницу то сам браузер не дает этого сделать

Comment: @Arsen вы хоть один учебник читали? там говорится что такое headers already sent

Comment: @Jean-Claude а вы  когда нибудь пользовались мозгом?  или вы всегда используете  пятую точку ? до того как ляпнуть тут комент вы хоть читали то что я писал ? по какой причине вы мне написали
> там говорится что такое headers already sent ??
к какому моему комменту это относится ?

Comment: @NONAME конечно вы не можете поставить php  header() после загрузки страницы, вам надо переместить весь ваш php код в начало страницы и там проводить проверки и после успешной регистрации делать редирект